# Android:Changing Intensity of the colour of TextView or Button

Tags: android, colors, android-xml

Within my application I have various coloured TextViews/Buttons. The problem is that they are too bright/intense on screen.

Is there a functionality that will tone down how bright/intense they are on screen?

**Screen Shot:**

[image]

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:background="#e4fbff" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSearchHome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text=" "
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSearchHomeDate"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/circle4"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:text="Date"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSearchHomeGame"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:text="Game"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSearchHomeMedValues"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle3"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:text="Meditation Values"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSearchHomeAttValues"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle2"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:text="Attention Values"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSearchHomeScore"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle4"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:text="Score"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Example of circle XML drawable being referenced by buttons:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#0e84de" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#4a6176" />

    <padding
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
         />

    <corners android:radius="8dp" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make the drawable little tranparent.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#330e84de" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#4a6176" />

    <padding
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
         />

    <corners android:radius="8dp" />

</shape>
```

Try this as your background. I used a transparent color. So #0e84de becomes #330e84de.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't/don't want to change the value of your colors in your Drawable, you have to change it at runtime.

Retrieve the RGB value of your color, convert it to HSV and reduce the saturation, convert back to RGB and apply the new color to your Drawable. (See Wikipedia for conversion formulas)

A bit overkill when you can simply change your color attribute in your Drawable.